# how to achieve hibernate second level cache on the query with joins?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

i am trying to achieve second level caching while logging in user.

my scenario:-
whenever a user is validated it needs to pull more details from other tables. like in this case, i am pulling data from userdetails table using inner join.

each time a user is validated it pulls the same data. so i don't want to keep executing query every time a user tries to login. in this case maybe i can make a use of second level cache.

unfortunately i'm not able to achieve second level cache of hibernate here.

**UserController**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping("/getUserDetails")
    public @ResponseBody List<UserDetailsMapping> userDetailsMappings(){
        return userDao.getUserDetails();
    }

}
```

**UserDao**

```
@Repository
public class UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<UserDetailsMapping> getUserDetails(){
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        String sql ="select u.username,ud.address,ud.height,ud.weight from
         User u inner join UserDetails ud \n" +
                "on u.username=ud.username where u.username='sagar' and 
                u.password='sagar';";
        Query query = session.createNativeQuery(sql,"userMapping")
                .setCacheable(true);
        List<UserDetailsMapping> list = query.getResultList();
        return list;
    }
}
```

**User.class**

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class User {


    @Id
    private String username;
    private String password;

**************constructors and getter setters**********
}
```

**UserDetails.class**

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "userMapping",
classes = {@ConstructorResult(targetClass = UserDetailsMapping.class,
columns = {
        @ColumnResult(name = "username",type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "address",type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "height",type = Integer.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "weight",type = Integer.class)
})
})
public class UserDetails {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String address;
    private String gender;
    private int height;
    private int weight;

   **************constructors and getter setters**********

}
```

**applicationContext Configuration**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.
         hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.test</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```